# How to match within two lines in JSON using REGEX?

Tags: json, regex

So the JSON is like:

```
  "foo": {
            "points": 23.67
        },
```

I'd like a regex to just match `23.67`.

I've tried `\"foo\":{\"points\":([^}"]*)` but it doesn't work.

There are multiple lines which contain `"points":` so just `\"points\":([^}"]*)` won't work.

Comment: Don't match _any_ lines with regex; use a JSON parser.

Comment: What language are you using? I'm sure this language already has a JSON parser (or 10) that you can easily use.

Comment: I only want to do it in regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring whitespace.

Try this instead:

```
\"foo\":\s*{\s*\"points\":\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjKKXV/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not take into account a few details:

- Between `"foo":` and `{` there can be spaces.
- After `{` there can be a *newline* and spaces.
- After `"points":` there can also be spaces.
- Between the string to capture (capturing group and "terminating" '}'
  there can also be a *newline* and spaces.

So, including the above missed details, and taking into account that `\s`
matches also *newline*, the whole regex can be as follows:

```
\"foo\":\s*{\s*\"points\":\s*([^}"]*)\s*}
```

Actually, your capturing group can be "more restrictive".
As the text to capture contains only digits and a dot,
it can be written as: `[\d\.]+`.
Note that I changed `*` to `+`, because the content cannot be empty.